# Why does my GPU immediately run out of memory when I try to run this code?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, torch, cuda

I am trying to write a neural network that will train on plays by Shakespeare and then write its own passages. I am using `pytorch`. For some reason, my GPU immediately runs out of memory. Note I am not running it on my own GPU; I am running it using the free GPU acceleration from Google Colab. I've tried running a different notebook using the GPU and it works, so I know it's not because I ran into some GPU usage quota or anything like that. Here is a link to the notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WNzmN-F3EOvy2HtHCQ0TyBYA5RsCCfN0?usp=sharing
so you can try running it yourself. Alternatively, I will paste the code below as well

notice i have a `print(i)` in the last for loop. when I run it, the only output I get from that `print` is a single `0`, and then I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-e6121e5b189f> in <module>()
     23     targets = targets.to(dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
     24 
---> 25     out, hidden = net(inputs, hidden)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    580         if batch_sizes is None:
    581             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,
--> 582                               self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
    583         else:
    584             result = _VF.lstm(input, batch_sizes, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias,

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 12.43 GiB already allocated; 5.88 MiB free; 15.08 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

it's running out of memory before it has even done a single batch!

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import re


with open('drive/MyDrive/colab/shakespeare.txt', 'r') as file:
  text = file.read()

print(text[:100])

chars = list(set(text))
index2char = dict(enumerate(chars))
char2index = {char: index for index, char in index2char.items()}

encoded = [char2index[word] for word in text]
print(encoded[:100])


seq_length = 50 

regex = '.{1,' + str(seq_length + 1) + '}'
dataset = np.array(re.findall(regex, text, flags=re.S))

batch_size = 10
n_batches = len(dataset) // batch_size
dataset = dataset[:n_batches * batch_size]


device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
print(device)

dataset = dataset.reshape(n_batches, -1)
print(dataset.shape)
print(len(dataset[0][0]))

def passage_to_indices(passage: str):
  return np.array([char2index[char] for char in passage])

class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, batch_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
    self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
  
  def forward(self, input, hidden):
    # lstm should take input of size (seq_length, batch_size, input_size)
    # and hidden of size (num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)
    out, hidden = self.lstm(input, hidden)
    return out, hidden

  def init_hidden(self):
    hidden = (
        torch.zeros(self.num_layers,
                    self.batch_size,
                    self.hidden_size,
                    dtype=torch.float32
                    ).cuda(),
        torch.zeros(self.num_layers,
                    self.batch_size,
                    self.hidden_size,
                    dtype=torch.float32
                    ).cuda()
    )

    return hidden

input_size = len(chars) # 65
hidden_size = 256
num_layers = 2
net = Net(input_size=input_size,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          hidden_size=hidden_size,
          num_layers=num_layers
          )

net = net.cuda()

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
  hidden = net.init_hidden()
  for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
    print(i)
    targets = torch.tensor([char2index[str(example[-1])] for example in batch])
    # dim passages = (batch_size, seq_length) 
    passages = np.array([passage_to_indices(str(example[:-1])) for example in batch])
    one_hot = F.one_hot(torch.tensor(passages), num_classes=input_size)
    inputs = one_hot.view(seq_length, batch_size, input_size)
    inputs = inputs.to(dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
    targets = targets.to(dtype=torch.float32).cuda()

    out, hidden = net(inputs, hidden)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it was a really stupid issue. I should have tried to run my code somewhere other than Google Colab before posting here. In case anyone has the same issue, here is how I solved it:

In Google Colab, click `Runtime --> Manage sessions`. I had a bunch of other active sessions there. I closed them, and now it runs fine.